# Unknown pseudo-op: .bss

Tags: assembly

I set my mac to run 32 bits.

And my asm code is

```
.data
        HelloWorldString:
            .asciz "Hello World of Assembly!"
        H3110:
            .asciz "H3110"
.bss
    .lcomm Destination, 100
    .lcomm DestinationUsingRep, 100
    .lcomm DestinationUsingStos, 100
.text
...
...
```

However, when I run

```
as -arch i386 -g -o StringBasics.o StringBasics.s
```

in Terminal, it prints

```
StringBasics.s:6:Unknown pseudo-op: .bss
```

I've searched around but am still quite lost on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like your assembler does not support the section named `.bss` (typical name for a section containing zeroed or not explicitly initialized C/C++ variables). Try simply removing the line with it.

Comment: see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000823-TPXREF101  -- it seems that there's no directive `.bss` but instead of segment name `__bss`